# ImageSearch command failing

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a hotkey that will find the google sheets "tools" menu, click on it, move down a few pixels and click on script editor. I could do this within google sheets but it doesn't have universal keybinds for this, I'd have to make a macro and I'd rather it just be universal.

```
SC163:: 
{
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight,  C:\Users\xx\Documents\AHK Scripts\gsheets-tools.bmp

    if ErrorLevel = 2
        tooltip Could not conduct the search.
    else if ErrorLevel = 1
        tooltip Image could not be found on the screen.
    else
        {
            mousemove, %FoundX%, %FoundY%, 50
            tooltip The image was found at %FoundX%x%FoundY%.
        }
    return
}
```

It was throwing error 2 until I hardcoded the entire image name. Now it only throws error 1, even if I have three copies of sheets open (one on each monitor). Is BMP not the best format to use here? I tried using

```
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, *n30 C:\Users\xx\Documents\AHK Scripts\gsheets-tools.bmp
```

to see if adding that allowance would helps, but failure. Any tips for using image search correctly? This isn't some sophisticated game function, just trying to find a toolbar and click on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `*n30` to just `*30`.

Also, by default, `ImageSearch` coordinates are per the active window and not the entire desktop, so using `A_ScreenWidth` and `A_SreeenHeight` might be problematic. While this isn't an issue if the window is maximized on your primary screen, it may present a problem if it's not maximized or is on a screen with a different resolution. If it's not maximized, it could be searching an area that goes beyond your display area, which might be an issue.

Possibly another issue (unverified) could be with Windows scaling. A lot of times a 2160p monitor defaults to 200% scaling (or is it 150%? w/e).

Since you're using BMP images, you may want to verify that it was saved as 16-bit or higher.

Notable quotes from the help file:

> All operating systems support GIF, JPG, BMP, ICO, CUR, and ANI images (BMP images must be 16-bit or higher).
>
> . . .
>
> The region to be searched must be visible; in other words, it is not possible to search a region of a window hidden behind another window. By contrast, images that lie partially beneath the mouse cursor can usually be detected. The exception to this is game cursors, which in most cases will obstruct any images beneath them.

Comment: Hmm, I just opened a sheet in Edge; for me, the coordinates for the bottom-right of "Tools" in the menubar is roughly 390, 170. So you may need to adjust it to be something like `ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 400, 200`. If that doesn't work, would you mind attaching your image file so this I can give it a try?

Comment: I can confirm that the picture from the link does not work. I created a new picture with the snipping tool (saved as PNG) and it worked on the first go without any variation value.

Comment: Thanks evan, I'll just retake pictures and try that!

Comment: I retook a picture and it worked on itself! Yay! But then it still doesn't work on the window it was screenshotted from. I wonder if there is something going on administratively. I can't run my ahk as admin right now but I'll test it again the next time I'm able. eid: by works on itself I mean it finds the image if it is open in paint. But it does not find "tools" on the web browser window.

Comment: Ok, the new picture plus a tolerance of 60 did it.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you, I'm very glad to help. I'm surprised it took such a high tolerance to make it work. If you don't mind sharing, I'm curious as to your setup with regard to monitor resolutions and scaling, as well as the software used to create the comparing image.

Comment: windows paint, two monitors one is 2560x1440 and the other is 1920x1200. with this picture I also switched to gif since jpg and png had failed me.

Comment: @J.G. Have you tried saving directly from the snipping tool? Also, what is the scaling of each monitor? (This can be found by right-clicking your desktop and clicking "Display settings". Each monitor has its own scaling and these can be different.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using this for Image Search 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWRAtvJq9ZE
It is very simple and works pretty good!

Comment: I downloaded that script but it had an error when I ran it and when I commented out the erroring line it didn't work correctly (missing part of the ui).